# ist/hat jmd/jmn auf etwas treten-auxillary and case

Tags: meaning-in-context

So I've been studying this verb "treten", and everything seems to make sense but for the following examples provided on DWDS:

> Er **ist mir** auf den Fuß getreten.

> Er **hat mich** auf den Fuß getreten.

They both mean the same thing, right? Still, I don't quite understand the logic behind the change of the auxillary and case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example describes an intentional act. It is basically the transitive: "er hat mich getreten" (= he kicked me), plus an adverbial (for the exact spot that got hit). Here, the "auf"-phrase is optional.

The first construction "Er ist mir auf den Fuß getreten" has two objects, neither can be omitted. Here, "treten" behaves like a verb of movement: he moved onto my foot (accidentally or intentionally) (= he trod / stepped on my foot). Movement verbs generally have a "be"-auxiliary.

(The obligatoriness comes from the "possession" relation between "me" and "foot". A possible alternative is, however: "Er ist auf meinen Fuß getreten", although the construction with "mir auf den Fuß" feels more idiomatic).